# How can I make a jsf commandLink look disabled?

Tags: css, jsf, frontend

I have a h:commandLink and I want it to look like is not clickable (i.e the link has a pale color and when you hover over it the cursor becomes *not-allowed* ).

I'm using the disabled attribute trying to achieve that but it doesn't perform the desired effect: the link doesn't have a pale color and when I hover over it the cursor doesn't become *not-allowed*. But when I click the commandLink it doesn't do anything, which is good but I'd prefer for it to have the properties previously defined.

Here's my code:

```
<h:commandLink  onclick="function()" href="#{request.contextPath}/create"
                         styleClass="#{condition ? 'enabled-link' : 'disabled-link'} mar-left-8 cl-blue"
                                      disabled="#{condition ? 'false' : 'true'}"
                                     data-scroll-goto="0" id="show"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"/>
                        <p:ajax/>
                      </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: commandLink and button sounds contradictory. What is corresponding html you want to achieve

Comment: So just apply the desired css class?

Comment: I'm applying the desired css class but it doesn't perform the desired effect

Comment: Please, post your code..

Comment: Done, sorry for not posting it earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the disabled attribute of the commandLink turns the link into a span tag instead of an anchor tag.

So my code displays on the browser in the following fashion:

```
<span href="/" id="show" 
 name="show" 
 class="disabled-link mar-left-8 cl-blue"> 
 <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

And the reason why the *disabled-link* class wasn't making any effect is because I was missing this peace of code on the css:

```
span.disabled-link {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5; }
```

Comment: You are right! In this case, disabled='true' only makes it disabled functionally. You have to manually style it the way you want.